# jQuery.ajax get beginning of data flushed by the server before the end of the response

Tags: http, jquery

When an HTTP request to a server takes a long time to complete, the server can send parts of the response, and the browser typically displays these parts, even if the response is not finished yet.

Now if I use `jQuery.ajax` instead of a normal browser request, do I have a way to get the first parts of the response data before completion ?

Answer (score 0):

you may just need to add:

```
async: false,
```

to your request to force the ajax request to wait for a response before continuing?

Comment: I don't want to wait for the response, I want to be notified each time the browser receives a part of the response.